# iPhone / IOS App Reinstall from App Store Has Old Badge and Value

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, badge, reinstall

When an app that has an app badge with a value is uninstalled and then installed again from the app store, it will have the "old" badge.  Is this desired behavior?  Is there a way to inform the installation / distribution not to use the "old" application badge?

The initial install does not have the badge.

This is all BEFORE that app is run after NEW installation.

Comment: did u find any answer to this ? I am having the same issue.

Comment: did you find the solution? or the reason why its happening.. if yes please post.

Comment: See below comment.  Have not revisited this for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to hide the "old" badge icon using

```
[[[UIApplication] sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

You can easily check if it's first open of your app using some values in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: ok, the whole deal here is that BEFORE the app is run after reinstallation the APP has the OLD badge.  Once the app starts all is well.  This is not a big issue, just trying to see why this is happening.  Probably a bug on APPLE's side, but wanting to see if anyone else has seen this.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, iOS remembers badge value (which is appeared on the app icon). So you have to wait for a short period of time (1 day maybe), and then try to install it again.